# Integrated squared density derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm having trouble understanding the working steps in the following screenshot, taken from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyTuN.png). $K(x)$ is a kernel density function, which is symmetric and integrates to 1 and $f(x)$ is a density function.
[image]
[image]

The second step is a simple change of variable $u=(x-y)/h$ but from there I can't follow anymore. I suppose it has something to do with integration by parts, but how come the other terms all disappear?

**Reference**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyTuN.png) Hall, P. and Marron, J.S. (1987). Estimation of integrated squared density derivatives, *Statistics & Probability Letters* 6: 109-115.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest is integration by parts: $m$ times with respect to $u$, then $m$ times with respect to $x$, and then another $m$ times with respect to $u$. I think a further condition on $K$ is required to explain the absence of boundary terms.

Comment: Thank you. So if, say, $m=1$ then $[f(x-hu)K'(u)]_{-\infty}^{\infty} = 0$ right? I can't think of any other properties of $K$ besides those listed above though.

Comment: @drawar: You hadn't specified that the integration extends to infinity. Functions are often (implicitly or explicitly) assumed to vanish sufficiently rapidly at infinity.